# Textfield Length Django

Tags: django

I am trying to get a len of a textfield in Django so I can manipulate it in my template since the name of the school is too long, it is overlapping in the PDF display. I found this old post here in SO [How to get the length of a TextField in Django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11937554/how-to-get-the-length-of-a-textfield-in-django)

I am trying to get the length of a school field which is related to another model.

```
x = Recipient.objects.get(id='1234551')
len(x.department.school)
```

This gives me an error:  object of type 'Recipient' has no len(). School is also a field and it seems to work on the old post. I just don't understand why it doesn't work in my end.

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that Department is a foreignkey of Recipient and School is Foreignkey of Department.

Comment: You will need to include your models so we can help better

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What kind of field is `x.department.school` ? Is that the `CharField` or the `ForeignKey`?

Or maybe it has to be something like `len(x.department.school.name)` ?

You will have to post your models for us to give a complete answer.

Comment: school is a foreignkey. You're correct Sir, I should've put it the x.department.school.name. May I know if len() works in FK too?

Comment: To my knowledge, `len()` does NOT work on `ForeignKey` fields, since those are usually integers in the database